# is recovery software helpful?

Tags: usb-storage

i have imation pendrive and in that i have security lock , and i forgot the password due to this i cant able to access the drive ,, and the only solution is to format it to use the drive but in that i have important files which i in need,, so is recovery software will help me to get my files back after formating ????

Comment: off-topic, not programming related

Answer (score 1):

Not really a coding question...  Your recovery software is more likely to be useful before you format the drive.  Some security lock software encrypts files, others don't.  If yours is in the latter category you should be able to recover your files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this forum is the correct one for asking this question.
Only programming questions are allowed here